# How to make sure that Tomcat6 reads CATALINA_OPTS on Windows?

Tags: tomcat, logging, grails, permgen

I have a Tomcat6 running on a Windows2003 machine.
I deployed 2 Grails apps on this server and I soon noticed that everything was crashing sometime after the deploy with a classic PermGen error.

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
 java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
 java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:632)
 java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:616)
 org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassLoaderForClassArtifacts.de 
...
```

So I found a common fix for this problem: increasing heap and permgen space with:

```
set CATALINA_OPTS="-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -XX:PermSize=128m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m"
```

Added into C:\apache-tomcat-6.0.26\bin\catalina.bat.
Unfortunately this didn't work, but the problem is that I'm not sure that Tomcat is picking it up. I checked various logs but these options are never printed out.
Is there a way to log them and make sure that Tomcat has read them?

EDIT: I tried to add the following JVM options with tomcat6w.exe:

```
-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
-XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled 
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
```

And nothing changed. I get a permGen after 2-3 minutes of uptime.
Any other idea?

Cheers!
Mulone

Comment: Good point: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_19\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll

Comment: This kind of question is for serverfault.com, i guess.

Comment: Tomcat developers recommend to keep your customizations separate. Use "%CATALINA_BASE%\bin\setenv.bat" file for setting the variables instead of modifying them inside "catalina.bat".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thank you all!
I finally solved the issue by adding:

```
-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
-XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:PermSize=128m
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
```

To the java options on tomcat6w.exe.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Actual way to do it (in Catalina.bat),

```
set "JAVA_OPTS=-Djava.awt.headless=true -server -Xms512m -Xmx2048m -XX:PermSize=512m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled"
```

add this line in such a position so that this JAVA_OPTS is transferred to any of _EXECJAVA command at the end of file (if-else nested). I personally write this line as first statement of this batch

Comment: Tomcat developers recommend to keep your customizations separate. Use "%CATALINA_BASE%\bin\setenv.bat" file for setting the variables instead of modifying them inside "catalina.bat".

Answer (score 1):

I actually set those as JAVA_OPTS for my JVM before starting the server

```
JAVA_OPTS=-Djvmarg='-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -XX:PermSize=128m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m'
```

Answer (score 0):

Look where you are setting it, use `echo [statements]` to troubleshoot, try setting it right before its passed to the VM, something like:

```
set CATALINA_OPTS="-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -XX:PermSize=128m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m"
_EXECJAVA% %JAVA_OPTS% %CATALINA_OPTS% %DEBUG_OPTS% 
-Djava.endorsed.dirs="%JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS%" -classpath "%CLASSPATH%" 
-Dcatalina.base="%CATALINA_BASE%" -Dcatalina.home="%CATALINA_HOME%" 
-Djava.io.tmpdir="%CATALINA_TMPDIR%" %MAINCLASS% %CMD_LINE_ARGS% %ACTION%
```

Make sure you have the right `EXEC_JAVA` not sure which version of the `.bat` file you have, but probably several `if` statements.

Also make sure these are valid arguments for your VM.

You can check your max heap size within your java code, use:

```
long heapMaxSize = Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory();
```

Just print it out, if its correct based on your settings, you have a bad memory leak, if its not, then `tomcat` is not picking it up.