# How do I properly set the permgen size?

Tags: java, tomcat, grails, jvm, permgen

I have this VM with tomcat, java, and grails in it. I've been getting permgen errors so I looked around and found the solution:

```
set JAVA_OPTS="-Xms256m -Xmx1024m -XX:PermSize=512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m"
```

I use SSH to access the vm and type the arguments above. I suppose that would fix the problem. Thing is, I wanted to make sure that I did it correctly. So I searched again on how I could check the current permSize and this is the solution I got:

```
jinfo -flag MaxPermSize 6444
```

6444 is the pid, and as a response, I got this.

```
-XX:MaxPermSize=85983232
```

Question: Is the value of the maxPermSize in bytes? because, if it is, then that would mean that the java_opts command didn't work. I am expecting to get 512m but 85983232 bytes = 82 mb.. Or am I seeing it wrong..? Can anybody enlighten me on this? D:

Comment: I assume you restarted the tomcat process? With ps -wwf 6444 you can see the full command that started the process. Check that your options are included. You can also start jconsole (included in jdk) and connect to the process, then check the General info tab and the Memory tab.

Comment: I haven't restarted tomcat. I think I forgot that process.. D: Sorry I'm kinda new to this deploying thing.. But I guess as a developer I should know this kind of stuff.. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You have to change the values in the **CATALINA_OPTS** option defined in the Tomcat Catalina start file. To increase the `PermGen` memory change the value of the `MaxPermSize` variable, otherwise change the value of the `Xmx`  variable.

**Linux & Mac OS:** Open or create `setenv.sh` file placed in the "bin" directory. You have to apply the changes to this line:

```
export CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -server -Xms256m -Xmx1024m -XX:PermSize=512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m"
```

**Windows:**

Open or create the `setenv.bat` file placed in the "bin" directory:

```
set CATALINA_OPTS=-server -Xms256m -Xmx1024m -XX:PermSize=512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m
```

Comment: Actually the advised way of setting this is by creating a setenv.bat (Windows) or setenv.sh (*nix) and putting the entries in there, Tomcat will pick these up and its easier to manage an upgrade

Comment: There are a lot of answers similar to this around but I found that this was the clearest and simplest phrased, very helpful.

Comment: Why change Xmx increase PermGen ?

Answer (score 21):

Don't put the environment configuration in catalina.bat/catalina.sh. Instead you should create a new file in CATALINA_BASE\bin\setenv.bat to keep your customizations separate of tomcat installation.

Comment: I submitted an edit to add this to the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

So you are doing the right thing concerning "-XX:MaxPermSize=512m": it is indeed the correct syntax. You could try to set these options directly to the Catalyna server files so they are used on server start.

Maybe this post will help you!

[How to make sure that Tomcat6 reads CATALINA_OPTS on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583757/how-to-make-sure-that-tomcat6-reads-catalina-opts-on-windows)

Comment: I am using linux. But I'll read this and see how it works. thank you so much for replying. :3

Answer (score -1):

Completely removed from java 8 +
Partially removed from java 7 (interned Strings for example)
[source](https://dzone.com/articles/java-8-permgen-metaspace)