# tomcat7 maxpermgen error, total memory doesn't match max memory

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, memory

I wrote an application that is deployed in tomcat 7.  It works fine in eclipse when testing.  When I try to deploy it in tomcat I get a maxpermgen error.  I gave it more than enough (1.7gb).  In eclipse it only has 512mb.

Here's the odd thing, going to the tomcat7 manager app here's what I get for memory usage:

Free memory: 87.01 MB Total memory: 118.18 MB Max memory: 1754.68 MB

My maxpermgen is obviously set, but what's with the total memory not matching?  How do I increase this?

Answer (score 1):

PermGen size is not the same thing as heap size (which is what you are configuring in the above command line).

See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262328/how-is-the-java-memory-pool-divided) for a description of the various java memory regions.

And see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11341494/how-do-i-properly-set-the-permgen-size) to configure PermGen for Tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by setting JAVA_OPTS -Xmx1500m -Xms1500m as a windows variable.  But my application is still throwing maxpermgen errors

Comment: what do you mean by "solving it" then? it sounds like you didn't solve anything.