# Getting OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space whiling executing maven build in jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins, tomcat7, maven-3

Triggering a CI build from git to jenkins
Using tomcat 7 server,maven 3,jdk 7

Comment: Have you tried increasing your memory? Is it Jenkins or your maven build that gets OOM? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11341494/how-do-i-properly-set-the-permgen-size for example..

Comment: can you tell java version and IDE name and version

Comment: maven build in jenkins

Answer (score 2):

Increase your permanent memory space by setting the JVM arguments like this

```
-XX:PermSize=512m  -XX:MaxPermSize=1028m
```

You could also increase the heap size like this

```
-Xms512m -Xmx1g
```

This would allocate in total of 2 GB memory (1g max for heap space and 1g max for perm generation space)