# Apache Tomcat Server OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, apache, server, tomcat7

I've been tried to start my Tomcat v7.0 server, but every time i try the same error occurs

```
20-jul-2018 8:05:38 org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
GRAVE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:222)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:83)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:819)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1702)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
```

I've already added the line `-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -Dspring.profiles.active=jndi,local` to my launch configuration.

I have a 4GB RAM, is it possible that i need more memory to start the server and the app?

Comment: @rustyx same error.

Comment: `-Xmx` won't help here because OOM happens in PermGen. Try to [increase PermGen size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11341494/how-do-i-properly-set-the-permgen-size). See more about PermGen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279449/what-is-perm-space)